# Illegal instruction (core dumped) upon compiling with SSE and -O3 options using latest g++ with a custom alignment allocator implementation

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sse, allocation

When using g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) to compile the following piece of code using the compiling command "g++ -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse2 -mssse3 -O3 Memory.cpp", the executable raises "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" upon execution.

It compiles and runs without problems using the same exact compiler flags using an older g++ version.  It also compiles and runs without problems when the compiler flags "-mssse3 -O3" is dropped or is replaced with a lower optimization level such as "-O2".

If usage with both the old and the newer g++ compiler, having the compiler flags "-msse2 -mssse3 -O3", and having a portable aligned memory allocator is a requirement, what options exist?  Is there a simple mistake in the following piece of code that could be easily fixed?  Finally, why did this error exist?

When using gdb, the line that triggers this error is: "memory[i] = (unsigned char)i;".

Thanks much in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::flush;
#include <stdlib.h>

void *aligned_alloc(int alignment, int size){
  const int pointer_size = sizeof(unsigned char *);
  const int requested_size = size + alignment - 1 + pointer_size;
  unsigned char *base = (unsigned char *)malloc(requested_size);
  if (base == NULL)  return NULL;
  unsigned char *start = base + pointer_size;
  const int trim_offset = (int)(((unsigned long long)(start+alignment-1)) & (alignment-1));
  unsigned char *aligned = start + alignment - 1 - trim_offset;
  *(unsigned char **)(aligned-pointer_size) = base;
  return aligned;
}
void aligned_free(void **aligned){
  if (*aligned == NULL)  return;
  unsigned char *base = *(unsigned char **)((unsigned char *)(*aligned) - sizeof(unsigned char *));
  free(base);
  *aligned = NULL;
}

int main(){
  unsigned char *memory = (unsigned char *)aligned_alloc(16, 120);
  if (memory == NULL){
    cout<<"ERROR: Unable to allocate memory."<<endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<120; i++){
    memory[i] = (unsigned char)i;
  }

  aligned_free((void **)&memory);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `aligned_alloc` is a standard function in more recent versions of glibc - I'm wondering if you're linking with that instead of your own function, or something like that - maybe try renaming your functions to `my_aligned_alloc`/`my_aligned_free` just as a test ?

Comment: What CPU are you using? In GDB, what _instruction_ (not line) and where causes the trap (try `(gdb) bt`, `(gdb) disas`)? What is the value of the registers that insn uses at that point? Also, you can deuglify somewhat your ptr arithmetic by casting `aligned` to `unsigned char**` and accessing `base` as `unsigned char* base = ((unsigned char**)aligned)[-1];`

Comment: @PaulR I thought so too but on second thought I discounted that because at least on my machine `aligned_alloc` is not mangled and its arguments are `size_t`, while here we're talking C++ and arguments of type `int`. Still, worth a try renaming it.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: good point - it's a C11 function, so not mangled. I also wondered though whether gcc might be doing something special with it, like it does with some other common library functions, where it just generates inline code rather than calling the standard library function.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this bug on `gcc version 4.8.3 20140627 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 212064] (SUSE Linux)` and an Intel i7-4700MQ Haswell CPU, but am getting a pile of SSSE3 `pshufb` instructions in the compiled code. Are you sure your CPU supports SSSE3 insns (as opposed to SSE3, which is different)? Those were for some time an Intel exclusive...

Comment: What CPU are you using?

Comment: Wow.  It never occurred to me that I would still encounter an Intel CPU that does not support the SSSE3 instruction set.  I did a cat /proc/cpuinfo and it clearly reports that flag being missing.  For completeness sake, I was comparing 1) Compiler = "g++ (GCC) 4.4.4 20100630 (Red Hat 4.4.4-10)" on CPU = "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4010U CPU @ 1.70GHz" vs 2) Compiler = "g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)" on CPU = "Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz".  I was under the impression that for sure it's my code being the culprit rather than the compiler.  I guess it could be hardware too!  Thanks!

Comment: Now how do I mark this as answered and close it?

Comment: It does not appear the line `unsigned char *base = *(unsigned char **)((unsigned char *)(*aligned) - sizeof(unsigned char *));` is equivalent to `unsigned char* base = ((unsigned char**)aligned)[-1];`.  In particular, I'm not sure compilers like indexing with a `[-1]` very well.

Comment: @Biolog In the context you gave, the correct expression in terms of `[-1]` (which is valid pointer arithmetic provided it dereferences an element within the same array) is: `unsigned char *base = *(unsigned char **)((unsigned char *)(*aligned) - sizeof(unsigned char *));` equates to `unsigned char* base = ((unsigned char**)*aligned)[-1];`, note the star in front of `aligned`.

Comment: @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist Thanks!  Learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by a CPU that didn't support the SSSE3 (Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3) instruction subset (in particular, a 3GHZ P4 of some flavor) trying to run code compiled for CPUs that support that instruction subset; simply dropping the `-mssse3` flag from the GCC command line should be enough to cause the offending instructions to go away.